# Get the first x elements of a Heapsort

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, heapsort

I'm preparing for a Google developer interview and working on algorithm questions. I need to figure out how to get the first *x* elements in an array of size *n* using the Heapsort algorithm. What part of the algorithm needs to be modified to get just the first *x* smallest elements?

This is the Heapsort algorithm from *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen Leiserson (page 155):

```
HEAPSORT(A)
{
  BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)
    for i = A.length down to 2
      exchange A[1] with A[i]
      A.heap-size = A.heap-size - 1
      MAX-HEAPIFY(A, 1)
}
```

These are the component algorithms:

```
BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)
  A.heap-size = A.length
  for i = floor(A.length / 2) down to 1
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, i)

MAX-HEAPIFY(A, i)
  l = LEFT(i)
  r = RIGHT(i)
  if l <= A.heap-size and A[l] > A[i]
    largest = l
  else largest = r
  if r <= A.heap-size and A[r] > A[largest]
    largest = r
  if largest != i
    exchange A[i] with A[largest]
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A, largest)
```

I can't figure out what part to modify to get the *x* smallest elements of the sorted array. Also need to find the time complexity of the modified algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the condition in MAX-HEAPIFY, we can change it into MIN-HEAPIFY, thus , we can easily obtain a min heap.

Then, the first element of this heap is the smallest element, we can remove this element, and bring the last element in the heap to the first element, and call MIN-HEAPIFY again to maintain the property of the heap. Continuing this process n time, we can obtain the first n smallest object.

Time complexity : log(m) + log(m - 1) + ... + log(m - n) ~ O(nlogm)